# How to simply this regex?

Tags: regex, preg-match, regex-group, regex-greedy

Can you help me simplify the following regex:

```
(^0x)([0-9a-f]{2})([0-9a-f]{2})([0-9a-f]{2})([0-9a-f]{2})([0-9a-f]{2})([0-9a-f]{2})
```

I want to the following results
if a string starts with 0x then it matches the next expression

```
0x010203040506
```

should produce

```
- group 1: 01

- group 2: 02

- group 3: 03

- group 4: 04

- group 5: 05

- group 6: 06
```

if string doesn't starts with 0x then there should be no match.

Thanks,

Comment: This couldn't get simplified since you have many capturing groups involved. But it could get a bit short: `(^0x)([0-9a-f]{2})((?2))((?2))((?2))((?2))((?2))`

Comment: What are you trying to match and what is your preferred outcome?

Comment: Or [`\A0x|\G(?!\A)[0-9a-f]{2}`](https://regex101.com/r/VLhrn0/1) if you are not going to validate simultaneously.

Comment: Capturing groups are meant to group several pattern together, while you're trying to create multiple copies of the same capturing group. Why so?

Answer (score 2):

You could make use of RegEx's [Subroutines](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-disambiguation.html#subroutines) to avoid using multiple character classes:

```
\A0x([0-9a-f]{2})((?1))((?1))((?1))((?1))((?1))
```

[Example](https://regex101.com/r/GxAEIE/4)

Using the [\G](https://www.regular-expressions.info/continue.html) anchor, you could go even shorter:

```
\A0x|\G(?!\A)[0-9a-f]{2}
```

[Example](https://regex101.com/r/GxAEIE/3)

Answer (score 1):

Moreover on comments of mine above, you may consider using `(?(DEFINE)...)` constructor in order to both validate and match:

```
(?x)(?(DEFINE)
    (?<X>[0-9a-f]{2})
)
\A0x(?=(?&X){5})|\G(?!\A)(?&X)
```

See [live demo here](https://regex101.com/r/YiPPQj/1)